# ble peripheral disconnected in background after some time

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheralmanager

I am using background fetch mode in plist . when we connect the peripheral to device its working in background for few moment but after 10-15 minute its automatically disconnect.
I want my peripheral is always connect .
which method is called when application wakeup from background ..

Comment: Have you specified background fetch mode or background Bluetooth mode?

Comment: ya already declared in plist ..Required background modes

Comment: Then in your didDisconnectPeripheral method you should reconnect to the peripheral

Comment: its not connected notification will gone  we cant detect tag button

Comment: Is it possible that your peripheral is shutting down?  If so there is nothing you can do from the central side apart from issuing a "connect".  Core Bluetooth will automatically connect and call didConnectPeripheral when the peripheral is seen again